# R Shiny, Delaying Function Execution until next iteration

Tags: r, shiny

**Problem**

Simply I want to print "loading" to a label before the rest of the code in a function is executed. Here is the code:

```
observe({
  alert()
})

alert <- function (t=''){
    output$text <- renderText(t)
}

observeEvent(input$analyse , {
 alert ("Loading...")

 someFunctionThatTakesVeryLong()

 alert ("Complete!")
}
```

**Result**

"Loading..." is never printed, only "Complete!" is. If "Complete!" code is removed, "Loading..." is only printed after the function is finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [withprogress](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/withProgress.html) function:

```
withProgress(someFunctionThatTakesVeryLong(), message="Loading", style="old")
```

This should create an alert style window (or notification style if style="notification") while the function is running.